# What is the proper way to compute predicted probabilities in a fixed-effects logistic regression?

Tags: r, logistic, predictive-models, interpretation, fixed-effects-model

Predicted probabilities are quite helpful to interpret the output of logistic regressions. One can compute a predicted probability as follows:
$$
P = \frac{exp(\beta + \beta_0)}{1 + exp(\beta + \beta_0)}
$$
where $\beta$ is a given coefficient and $\beta_0$ is the intercept.

I am trying to compute the predicted probabilities of a fixed-effects logistic regression, where there by default lots of intercepts. Consider this example in `R`. How would you compute the predicted probability of `dist_km`?

```r
library(fixest)
data(trade)
fe <- feglm(+(Euros > 1e6) ~ dist_km + Product | Year, trade)
summary(fe)

#GLM estimation, family = gaussian, Dep. Var.: +(Euros > 1e+06)
#Observations: 38,325 
#Fixed-effects: Year: 10
#Standard-errors: Clustered (Year) 
#         Estimate Std. Error   t value   Pr(>|t|)    
#dist_km -0.000206 0.00000166 -124.2128 7.2167e-16 ***
#Product  0.001405 0.00013337   10.5380 2.3094e-06 ***
#---
#Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
#Log-Likelihood: -23,304.5   Adj. Pseudo R2: 0.078249
#           BIC:  46,735.6     Squared Cor.: 0.098652
```

I'm thinking of using the weighted mean intercept of all fixed effects as $\beta_0$ (`weighted.mean(fixest(fe)[1], table(trade$Year) / sum(table(trade$Year)))`). Does it make sense?

Comment: Do you mean random or mixed effects? I assume `feglm` means "fixed effects GLM", but the `|` notation gets used for random effects, so I am confused. // Are you predicting the probability of being above `1e6`? Why not predict the number of euros? Binning into "over a million" and "under a million" destroys information and tends to be discouraged.

Comment: I mean models with varying intercepts. Yes, I'm predicting that; this is for the sake of the example, just to have a binary outcome. I'm not planning on binning the outcome in my real data set, it's a binary outcome.